# If $A^{1/2}B^{1/2}=0$. Why $BA=0\;?$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space.

> Let $A,B\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$ be such that $A^{1/2}B^{1/2}=0$. Why
>   $$BA=0\;?$$

Comment: Does $\mathcal{L}(E)^+$ mean the set of positive-definite (symmetric) linear operators $E\to E$?

Comment: @Arthur $S\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$ iff.$S\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ and $\langle Sx\;, \;x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in E$

Comment: Positive-semidefinite, then. Fair enough.

Comment: @Arthur If $S\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$ then $S^*=S$.

Comment: And hermitian, not symmetric. You did say _complex_ Hilbert space, I should've seen that.

Comment: @Arthur Yes you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiplying by $A^{1/2}$ on the left and by $B^{1/2}$ on the right you get $AB=0$. Then
$$
BA=B^*A^*=(AB)^*=0. 
$$